# Remove # from href jQuery

Tags: jquery, href

My href adds automatically # in the link..
With # in the href my link doesn't work anymore..

Does anyone know how I can remove it?
I have tried many options but without success ..

Here is my code

```
var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $(".article-body"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
    baseHeight   = 0,
    $el;

$pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

$("#menu").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find(".article-body")
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + ".article-body", function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                        $pageWrap.animate({
                            height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                        });
                    });
                    $("#menu a").removeClass("current");
                    $("#menu a[href='"+newHash+"']").addClass("current");
                });
            });
    };

});

$(window).trigger('hashchange');
```

Example of link

```
<li><a href="index.php?page_id=104">Home</a></li>
```

Thanks, Jens

Comment: If you use `location.hash` methods you are manipulating the hash, that's all parts of the URL that is after `#`. Maybe you need to manage `window.location` without hash to avoid the `#` to appears

Comment: there is no hash value in the anchor.....;)